# What is the definition of "the baseline of parent box"?

Tags: css

I have trouble understanding the following excerpt from [10 Visual formatting model details
– W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html).

**The excerpt:**

> baseline:
>   Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with the parent's baseline.

What does "the baseline of the parent box" mean in this context?
Does "parent box" refer to the line-box or the box established by the parent element? How do I calculate the "baseline of the parent box"?

Comment: I think you are confusing several definitions relating to this model. I think that you are looking for the definition of a strut.

Answer (score 12):

Check the bottom of this answer for an interactive version of this answer which will help you to verify statements from this answer on your own. This answer has been based on the post by Vincent De Oliveira on [his blog](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align). It's a must-read.

## What is baseline?

The image below, and many other images alike specify a basline, but what is it exactly?
[image]

## Inline text elements are not the same height...

To measure the height of an inline text element I will use the term **content-area**. Content-area of these elements for Windows is calculated as follows:

`Content-area=(Win Ascent + Win Descent)/Em Size * Font Size`

See a few examples below:

- Merriweather Sans has a content-area of 25px because (2014+560)/2048*20≈25px
- Noto Sans has a content-area of 27px because (2189+600)/2048*20≈27px

You can find these values, for example, using FontForge, as shown on the screenshots below:

#### Merriweather Sans (right), Noto Sans (left)

[image]

In this case for each font we have [content-area]=[line-box] and this is a special case in which you can measure the content-area of the element with dev-tools:

[image]

## How to align text elements to make text readable?

To do this you use the baseline.

In the example below you can see that increasing the line-height doesn't increase the content-box (the colored area), but it does increase the line-box of the orange inline element. Furthermore, notice that **both elements are mutually aligned along their baseline.** The baseline is defined by each font separately. However, when two different fonts align along their baseline, the resulting text is easily readable.

[image]

This is an image with the baseline showed as a green line: [image]

In the example below, the orange element is aligned in respect to the top of the parent's content area. However, the tomato colored element is aligned in respect to the baseline of the **strut** of the parent. A strut is a zero-width character which starts the line-box of the parent.

It might seem that the tomato colored element has moved up, but it is not the case. Its position relative to the strut has not changed.

[image]

## Conclusion

A baseline is a line which typeface authors use to design their fonts and make different fonts "mutually compatible". The baseline is chosen so that a text composed out of different fonts, which all have their own content-area, can be aligned along the baseline and remain easily readable.

A parent baseline is a baseline of the parent's strut, which is a zero-width character with a defined baseline which helps to align inline elements.

---

## Interactive version of this answer

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans');

span {
  margin: 0;
}

p.pr {
  background-color: blue;
}

span.mw {
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
}

span.ar {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<h1>What is baseline?</h1>
The image below, and many other images alike specify a basline, but what is it exactly?
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvhU4.png">
<br><br>
<h1>Inline text elements are not the same height...</h1>
To measure the height of an inline text element I will use the term <b>content-area</b>. Content-area of these elements for windows is calculated as follows:
<p>Content-area=(Win Ascent + Win Descent)/Em Size * Font Size</p>
<p>See a few examples below:</p>
<ul>
  <li>Merriweather Sans has a content-area of 25px because (2014+560)/2048*20≈25px <span class="mw">Abg</span></li>
  <li>Noto Sans has a content-area of 27px because (2189+600)/2048*20≈27px <span class="ar">Abg</span></li>
</ul>
<p>You can find this values using for example FontForge, as shown on the screenshots below:</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/h0th3Rv.png"></td>
    <td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/aRymbaf.png"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
In this case for each font we have [content-area]=[line-box] and this is a special case in which you can measure the content-area of the element with dev-tools:
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W8i6.png">
<h1>How to align text elements to make text readable?</h1>
<p>To do this you use the baseline.</p>
In the example below you can see that increasing the line-height doesn't increase the content-box (the colored area), but it does increase the line-box of the orange inline element. Furthermore, notice that <b>both elements are mutually aligned along their baseline which is defined by the font itself.</b> The baseline is defined by each font separately. However, when two different fonts align along their baseline, the resulting text is easily readable.
<p class="pr">
  <span class="mw">Abg (line-height=40px)</span><span class="ar">Abg</span>
</p>
This is an image with the baseline showed as a green line: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmoIL.png">
<br><br>
In the example below, the orange element is aligned in respect to the top of the parent's content area. However, the tomato colored element is aligned in respect to the baseline of the <b>strut</b> of the parent. A strut is a zero-width character which starts the line-box of the parent.
<br><br>
It might seem that the tomato colored element has moved up, but it is not the case. Its position relative to the strut has not changed.
<p class="pr">
  <span class="mw" style="vertical-align:top;">Abg</span><span class="ar">Abg</span>
</p>
<h1>Conclusion</h1>
<p>A baseline is a line which typeface authors use to design their fonts. The baseline is chosen so that a text composed out of different fonts, which all have their own content-area, can be aligned along the baseline and remain easily readable.</p>
<p>A parent baseline is a baseline of the parent's strut, which is a zero-width character with a defined baseline which helps to align inline elements.</p>
```

Comment: Because you've made a very good job of trying to explain a complex issue, I'm going to pick a little hole in it. Take a look at https://jsbin.com/kiyofofoka/edit?html,css,output. You'll see that the `.child` element, which is `vertical-align:baseline` is not aligned with the strut, but aligned with the baseline of its parent element, which is itself deliberately offset from the strut's baseline. This is what the spec means in Boltclock's quote: "with respect to a parent inline element, *or* to the strut of a parent block container element"

Comment: By the way, "A strut is a zero-width character which starts the line-box of the parent." would be better expressed as "A strut is a zero-width character which starts **each** line-box of the **containing block**.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks for providing relevant information which improves the answer and clarifies this concept even more. In the answer I have considered a text-node as an anonymous element which is a child of an explicit element like body, span, p etc. But your correction fits probably better with the specs hence I will apply your recommendation to the answer when I get a moment to fix the formatting in the answer as well. Right now I get a formatting issue ;<

Comment: Also it should be noted that the precise definition of baseline should be given in respect to the geometry of the font, but such a definition would over-complicate the answer. Hence I haven chosen to provide some hints and leave the rest to the reader's intuition.

Comment: Please note a minor error with "right" and "left" being transposed in the title of the FontForge screencaps ("Merriweather Sans (right), Noto Sans (left)"), as compared to the visible window titles.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for remarking it. I am aware of it. After posting the answer the markup in the answer got somehow corrupted because I get a formatting error whenever I try to save my edit. If not for that error, this would be solved right after I have posted the answer because that's when I have noticed it. Anyhow, after fixing the formatting error, I will make sure to correct that as well!

Answer (score 0):

The spec tells you what the parent box refers to just a couple of paragraphs above:

> The following values only have meaning with respect to a parent inline element, or to the strut of a parent block container element.

So the parent box refers to the box generated by the parent element, and you calculate the baseline of the parent box just like you would any other element.

Comment: -1 because you try to explain something what the op doesn't understand with something else what he is unlikely to understand by assuming, without any evidence, that he knows what a "strut" is, or "...you calculate the baseline of the parent box just like you would any other element...". Why would you assume, for example, that he knows how to " calculate the baseline of the parent box"? And why would you assume that he knows what a "strut" is?

Answers like this just spread confusion and make people feel dumb to something what is otherwise a valid question about a difficult topic.

Comment: @Bright: The context of the question makes it clear that the asker is deciding whether the "parent box" refers to a line box or the box established by the parent element. The sentence you quote was specifically designed with that context in mind - the asker doesn't need to know what a strut is. And I didn't assume they knew how to calculate the baseline of the parent box - I said that they can do so the same way they would for any other element. It's reasonable to assume they already know how to calculate the baseline of the element itself and are just asking how to align it wrt its parent.

Comment: The question asks from the title "what is the definition of parent box". In the case of your answer, you have answered a question which asks what does "baseline of parent box" *refer to* in a specific context. Furthermore, it seems to me that the op is confusing definitions. But on a second thought, the question does seem ambiguous in that respect and might be understood both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Neither did I find a specific definition,and according to the specification:

> The following values only have meaning with respect to a parent inline element, or to the strut of a parent block container element

You can infer that ,if there is a text node as child in the parent box ,the baseline of the child text node is the baseline of the parent box.

For example:

```js
.parent {
  display: inline;
  background:pink;
  font-size:40px;
  font-family:Microsoft Yahei;
  line-height:2;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}
.element-child {
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   textNode child of parent 
  <span class="element-child">
    element-child with another font-size
  </span>
</div>
```

[image][image]

Whatever with or without child text node,the baseline of parent box is in the same position which is equal to the baseline of the child text node.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [this picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Typography_Line_Terms.svg) to see what exactly is the [baseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29).

Now, let's demonstrate what the doc want to say:

[image]

When you define the `vertical-align: baseline` then the element is aligned to the baseline of the parent element's baseline as in the above picture.

Comment: -1 No, it's not the child element itself that gets aligned to the parent's baseline, but the bottom margin edge of the child element and it only occurs when the box of the child element doesn't have a baseline. Furthermore, this is not an answer to this question. You have depicted how to align the bottom edge of a child element's box to the baseline of the parent when the baseline of the parent has already been computed. The op wants to know how to compute the baseline of the parent when it is not given.