# Empty table-cell taller than non-empty

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I'm struggling with a rendering issue (that might be a bug in Firefox, because Chrome and Edge look fine)

An empty `<td>` (table cell) makes the whole row taller **if** there's `padding` and `vertical-align` applied to this cell (or the containing row). If the table-cell is non-empty - the height issue is gone. Adding a stupid `&nbsp;` fixes this.

Here's the code example

```css
table {float:left;margin-right:10px} /* so tables are side-by-side just to demonstrate the bug */

td {
  vertical-align:baseline;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>this table is taller</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>this table is shorter</td>
    <td>beacuse there's text here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/snhvc6dx/10/

Anyone faced anything similar and/or knows a workaround?

PS. I'm on Firefox 62.0b6

UPDATE: the `vertical-align:baseline` is very (!) often added by "CSS-reset" boilerplates for many front-side frameworks, so it was not my choice. As for the "why would anyone need an empty `td`?" well, this table is rendered at runtime, there's just no data in the database for that cell.

Comment: it's related to baseline alignment but since it's not the same in all the browsers not easy to tell why

Comment: If you didn't like my answer, you need to be more specific in what you're looking for. Explain why you want an empty td element and what purpose it serves.

Comment: @ChrisHitchcock There could be many reasons why there's an empty table cell, but that's not important to the question. The question asked why an empty table cell creates a different baseline than a cell with text.

Comment: @StevenLambert "and/or knows a workaround?"

Comment: Just for the record: I haven't downvoted anyone's answer (and never ever did, b/c downvoting sucks).

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question itself** not just on an external site.

Comment: I reckon this is a bug in Firefox. It looks to me like when a cell box contains no line boxes, Firefox is taking its baseline to be the bottom of the padding-box, hence the text in the cell with content vertically aligns with that creating the space above that text. This would be effectively consistent with the definition of the baseline for empty inline-blocks. But the definition of the baseline for empty cell boxes is different. There, the baseline is the bottom of the content box, in which case there is no need for the extra space above the text to enforce the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know exactly the issue but you can rely on pseudo element to add an empty element and it will be the same like adding `&nbsp;`:

```css
table {float:left;margin-right:10px} /* so tables are side-by-side */

td {
  vertical-align:baseline;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
td:after {
 content:"";
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>this table is taller</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>this table is shorter</td>
    <td>beacuse there's text here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain this is the issue but based on some experimentation it would seem to coincide.

The baseline of text is an interesting thing (explained [very well in this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193355/what-is-the-definition-of-the-baseline-of-parent-box)). Essentially text elements can have different heights based on the font used. This height determines where the baseline of the text is.

When looking at Firefox font inspector, the default font for a text element is Times New Roman (or whatever your browsers default is), but for the empty cell, there is no font assigned.

[image: Firefox devtools font inspector]

It would seem that Firefox "no font" font has a different baseline than Times New Roman. You can verify this by creating two `<span>` tags with the same senario and seeing the baseline of the element box.

[image: Span element with text showing baseline box]
[image: Empty span element with a higher baseline]

When the elements are aligned to the baseline, the empty element has a different baseline so the text gets pushed down to match it.

Since it seems to be a Firefox issue, I don't know if there's much you can do to fix the combination other than not to use `vertical-align: middle` in the table and instead use `top`, `middle`, or `bottom`.

```css
table {float:left;margin-right:10px} /* so tables are side-by-side */

td {
  vertical-align:top;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>this table is taller</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>this table is shorter</td>
    <td>beacuse there's text here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you can't avoid it, then @Temani's answer would seem to be the best course of action.

Comment: Yes it's for sure related to baseline but we cannot provide accurate explanation when it behaves differently so it can be a firefox but OR it can be a bug in all the other browsers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug or undefined behaviour. You can make them equal height by setting the same line-height for example line-height: 30px

Comment: this will simply make the issue not visible by increasing the second table height which may be not good

Answer (score -1):

If you're setting up for future content below the first i'd use colspan. If you're not needing more rows before the first, just drop the second td

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>this table is taller</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>more content</td>
    <td>even more content</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>this table is shorter</td>
    <td>beacuse there's text here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>I has content 2 bars of content</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

so like that if you're needing it to go across both.

If your table won't have additional content, drop the second td

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td> this table is taller</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/snhvc6dx/32/

Keep in mind, this won't resize without making your tables responsive, so as the screen gets smaller your tables will stack on top of each other instead of remaining side by side.

Comment: before assuming that the OP downvoted you, can you first explain how you are answering the question? I see nothing related to the question

Comment: @TemaniAfif his question was related to a workaround for the problem. Getting rid of the issue, as well as an empty bordered space seems to be a workaround for the issue. "and/or knows a workaround?"

Comment: so why not simply removing the whole table and use divs? it's also a better workaround ...

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/snhvc6dx/11/

so, you are tellig the browser that the text should be set baseline but you're  padding the cell from the bottom baseline.

just set vertical-align to middle

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

or to top if the text should stay on top of the cell...without padding-bottom